# How I can get elements from dictionary and add into array?

Tags: c#, .net

I have IDictionary<string, int>. I need to get keys and values from dictionary in string format and add into string[] array. I need to do it because I want to pass that text in function and that function takes string array.
I have that code for getting value:

```cs
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in dict)
{
    dataList.Add(kvp.Key + " " + kvp.Value.ToString());
}
```

I've created list and add in that list keys and values. After I was thinking to create for loop and from list add elements into array, but have error. Loop:

```cs
string[] txtArr;
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i++)
{
    txtArr[i] = dataList[i];
}
```

Error: System.NullReferenceException. I don't understand where is the problem. From what I read about that error, I understood it raised because something is `null`. But if I'm trying print in console dictionary or list all is OK, there isn't `null`, also `i` is `int` and `= 0`. Where is the problem?

Comment: *But if I'm trying print in console dictionary or list all is OK, there isn't null, also i is int and = 0. Where is the problem?* and the destination ?

Comment: txtArr is null. Try `string[] textArr = new string[dataList.Size()]`.

Comment: also using linq makes it one-liner`dict.Select(kvp=>kvp.Key + " " + kvp.Value).ToArray()`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is not instantiated, dude:

```
string[] txtArr = new string[dataList.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i++)
{
  txtArr[i] = dataList[i];
}
```

or you can do it like this:

```
string[] txtArr = dataList.ToArray();
```

or you can do it like this:

```
string[] txtArr = dict.ToList().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, dude :)

Comment: Anytime :). Mark it as true if you found it useful, please.

Comment: Why the call to `ToList`?  You are taking a dictionary, making a copy of it as a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` and then eventually taking this to create an array with the `ToArray` call.  No a problem if the initial collection is small, but serious if you have a large collection to start

Comment: Yes. You are right, the third answer can have some performance issues on large collections.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the string array.

```
string[] txtArr = new string[dataList.Count];
```